# Building a table with AJAX based on a PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a "draw-table.php" File, which is built up like this:

```
<?php

    function build_table($draw-me) {

        $html_output = "<html><tr><td>".$draw-me."</td></tr></html>";

        echo $html_output;

    }

?>
```

Now with my jquery html id like to put this table exact on a distinct Position. Do do this I have to Hand over the variable $draw-me, which contains a number. To do this I used the following code:

```
<html>
<div id="ajaxtest"></div>
<div id="button" style="background-color:#00FFFF">klick me</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$hand-over = 1;  
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#ajaxtest").click(function(){

        $.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: 'draw-table.php',
                 success: function(data) {
                 $("ajaxtest").html($hand-over);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
</html>
```

I also don't actually know is the echo command is the best way of solving this or should I use a return value?

Thank for your help.

Comment: Echoing HTML should work fine*, however you have several syntax issues. Your PHP code is missing a closing `"`, and the selector in your jQuery object is incorrect. You should also use the `html()` method to append the response, as `text()` will encode the HTML. * While HTML will work, it's generally considered better practice to just pass the data in JSON and then build the HTML of the table on the client. This reduces the amount of data having to be sent in requests, the amount of work the server has to do, and makes XSS slightly less likely.

Comment: okay, I had done this recommendation and edited my post. But still nothing happend.

Comment: I did. I have Problems with line   $("ajaxtest[$draw-me]").html(data); I dont know if this is correct. When i trying this, nothing happens :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and pay attention to @Rory McCrossan what he said

draw-table.php

```
<?php

    $drawme = $_POST['handover'];
    echo $html_output = "<table border='1'><tr><td>".$drawme."</td></tr></table>";

?>
```

html codes :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<button>Klick Me !</button>
<div id="ajaxtest"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'draw-table.php', //compare this line with yours
                data: {handover : 1},
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#ajaxtest").html(data); // and look at this line
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great, that one is working fine. I forgot to set the POST in the draw-table.php, and also the needing of a function is obsulet. What does the last lines "data:" and "success:" mean? Should It be     data: {handover : $handover}

Comment: data is your posted variable and success return the posted file content to your <div id="ajaxtest"></div> line. mean is if post be successful return the content of draw-table.php to <div id="ajaxtest"></div>.

Comment: Grat, if I say data: {handover : $handover} and Prior I define var $handover = 2; then the 2 is post correctly :)

Comment: {handover : 1} only change here its enough